# IE7 and IE8 will not display my simple horizontal CSS menu correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a menu working in all major browsers except IE7 and IE8. Here is the working menu:
http://jsfiddle.net/DtxWt/

However, In IE7 and IE8, it will display as shown here: 
http://imgur.com/gcByA

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nav` is an HTML5 element and IE7 & 8 do not understand HTML5. I believe IE is interpreting your HTML as `<nav></nav><ul><li>...` Therefore, your CSS is not being applied. You'll want to look into using something like http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/ for filling in the missing functionality.

Comment: Thanks. That solved it for IE8. IE7 is now applying the CSS, but the menu is aligned to the left, whereas all the other browsers are showing it properly in the center.

Comment: Actually I said the same thing before him "you may also use a div #nav instead of nav" but ok..

Comment: Actually Mike provided me with a better answer. I can continue to use HTML5 syntax and support older browsers as well instead of wrapping my Navigation inside a meaningless div.

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block` with ul is not necessary from what i see, let it at block
and probably add a `<div class="clearer"></div>` defined in css: `.clearer: clear:left;`
you may also use a div #nav instead of nav